# Controller+Action Routing in OpenUI5?

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

In many MVC frameworks, routes are set up like the following:

```
route.add(
{
   pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
}
```

This pattern would translate `http://myapp/products/edit/5` to the `products` Controller, in the `edit` action, passing `5` as an argument. Importantly with this method, the Controller is invoked first, and the Controller returns a View, like the following:

```
class ProductsController
{
     public ActionResult EditAction(String id)
     {
          return View("Edit.view.html");
     }
}
```

Does this approach to MVC exist in OpenUI5? Would it be possible to implement with custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The view definition allows you to define a controller name which is then used to instantiate the controller. Inverting this would require a lot of changes in the core.